# How to convert a Java object to JSON object in Eclipse

Tags: java, json, eclipse

My requirement is to convert a plain Java object to JSON format -

The Java object has following format -

```
Record Id: 168349200
 Name:  jane
 City:  abababa
 State:  ababab
 Insertion Date:  18/04/2017 10:16:17
```

I have gone through some tutorials and found that GSON library is a way to do it. I tried to install the gson jar  in my Eclipse project (using Eclipse Mars Release (4.5.0)).

But when I do -

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
```

in the class where I want to do the conversion of the Java object to JSON it throws an exception.

I think I have not added the GSON jar file properly.

Can some one please help.

Thanks.

Comment: No, if it truly threw a runtime exception it means you added the JAR correctly.  A missing JAR is more likely to give you a compile time error. What is the error?  Cut & paste the language you see.

Comment: Do you need to use GSON yes or yes?? I have solve that problem using ObjectMapper. Let me know if you are interested in the ObjectMapper approach, and I will share some scripts

Comment: @duffymoIt is a compile time error - It says - "The import com.google cannot be resolved"

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre No I dont need to use a GSON. My requirement is to convert the Java object to JSON so that it can be consumed by a REST API. Yes please tell me about ObjectMapper approach. I am new so anything that do the job quickly is fine. Thanks

Comment: if you want to import the jar file into your eclipse project , copy the jar file into your eclipse source folder , right click on the jar file , select **build path** -> **add to build path** . that should do it.

Comment: An extra comment, if GSON is not a must, I would recommend you to remove it from title of the question. Because other users may come up with different solutions to convert a Java Object into JSON

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = null;
    try {
        jsonString = gson.toJson(javaObject);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I am not being able to use the library "import com.google.gson.Gson" gives me compile time error

Comment: @bably I haven't any problem with importing this library in newer version of the Eclipse - Neon.3.

Answer (score 0):

From Java Object to Json using ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

MyObject mObject = new MyObject();

String jsonObject ="";


mObject.setField1(value1);
mObject.setField2(value2);
mObject.setField3(value3);

try {
            jsonObject = objMapper.writeValueAsString(mObject);
            System.out.println(jsonObject); //You can then store it in a file

     } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

You should add these imports:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

And in the pom.xml these lines:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I am very new to Java EE. In Eclipse Mars Release (4.5.0) I have created a simple Java project where I don't see the pom.xml file. To get the pom.xml file what type of project do I need to create in Eclipse? Thanks.

Comment: If you created a Java Project you can convert it into Maven like this: Right Click over project name -> Configure -> Convert to Maven.

However you may need to have a Maven plug in Eclipse and some dependencies stored in your computer. The topic is quite complex to explain in a comment on here so I would recommend you to look for some tutorials about how to create a simple Maven Project. And then you try the solution.

Comment: By the way, if you are starting you may thing that learn Maven is a waste of time, that you don't need it for simple projects, but trust me it will really easy your life as a developer and the sooner to get use to it the better

Comment: Alore - Thanks, I actually need to get the project done soon in 7 days so will have to look into Maven in the near future. Thanks for your suggestion.